# ExtJS - Dynamically add CheckBox to Form

Tags: forms, extjs, checkbox, extjs3, fieldset

I'm trying to dynamically add new form components to a fieldset inside a form and I'm struggling with the checkbox component.

I'm getting the "TypeError: Ext.form.Checkbox is not a constructor" error on firebug. Here's my code:

```
...
 Ext.getCmp('component1').add(new Ext.form.DisplayField({value: "aValue"}));
 Ext.getCmp('component1').doLayout();

 Ext.getCmp('component2').add(new Ext.form.Checkbox({fieldlabel:"aLabel",
                                     name: "aName"}));
 Ext.getCmp('component2').doLayout();
 ...
```

Both components (component1,component") are `xtype:fieldset` and look exactly the same. 
The first component, the `DysplayField` works correctly but the checkbox doesn't.

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need check the layout of component2. or compare the layout between component1 and component2. Try to set the layout as the same.

Comment: Indeed there was something wrong with the fieldset container (don't know what it was, deleted it and created new one and voilá)

Comment: @user650749, how this would be the answer, please explain with the code